# render(controller()) throws Fatal error: Call to a member function getRelativePath() on a non-object

Tags: php, symfony, twig, sonata

I've call it in common template for render google plus signin button, and this error do not appear only on homepage http://mydomain.local/ but when I go to any another page like http://mydomain.local/somepage this error appear.

any ideas what is that can be?

```
{{ render(controller('MyNamespaceMyBundle:MyController:loginButton')) }}

public function loginButtonAction()
    {
        return $this->render('MyNamespaceMyBundle:MyController:button.html.twig',array(
            'client_key' => $this->config['client_key']
        ));
    }
```

that's it, what else code you need?

Comment: You need to add the code of your template and from the controller so that we can help you

Comment: ok, @KhorneHoly see my updates

Comment: does that function hast a Route defined so that it can be found?

Comment: We're barking up the wrong tree here. **Where is the controller that contains a `getRelativePath()` method call?**

Comment: @KhorneHoly yes, it has route, I can access to that action directly.

Comment: @sjagr controller located under my custom namepspace folder src/Mynamespase/MyBundle/Controller/MyController.php 

my general question is why I see how render(controller working only on homepage, when it not working on other pages. I am confused because all pages (and home) use same base template in which I call this render(controller( method

Comment: When I ask where, I mean post the contents of it...

Comment: @sjagr this is standard component sonata-project/page-bundle/Twig/Extension/PageExtension.php line 282

`$sitePath = $this->siteSelector->retrieve()->getRelativePath();`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I was trying to render a twig template from a page that was included in the `sonata_page.ignore_route_patterns`, [embedding a controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers):

```
{% render(controller('AcmeDemoBundle:Controller:action', {param1 : 'value1'})) %}
```

And got the same exception, `Call to a member function getRelativePath() on a non-object`.

*Sonata\PageBundle\Twig\Extension\PageExtension*'s controller function is checking if it's defined a `pathInfo` attribute, if not, it's retrieved from the relative path of the site selector. Since my route was excluded from `sonata_page`, it couldn't. Hence the exception.

So basically, I just passed the required attribute and problem solved:

```
    {% set pathInfo = path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), 
        app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')) %}
    {% render(controller('AcmeDemoBundle:Controller:action', 
        {param1 : 'value1', pathInfo: pathInfo})) %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's revealed in the comments that you are trying to utilize Sonata's Page Bundle. I found that [others have experienced this issue](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataPageBundle/issues/398). According to the discussion thread you have either:

1. Not configured a site
2. Configured the site with a "bad host"

Make sure you follow the steps outlined in the [Getting started](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/page/master/doc/reference/getting_started.html) docs. Specifically, it seems you probably need to execute this command:

```
php app/console sonata:page:create-site
```

Comment: yeah.. I;ve also googled it before create this topic on skackoverflow

`php app/console sonata:page:create-site` will only create new record in database table  "page__site", it not helping alt all. I will ask in third time, maybe u do not understand question... **why render(controller()) working on homepage but not working in other pages, even in case that all pages, including homepage, using same base layout**

Comment: @Unstaged What settings did you use when you created the site? The problem doesn't come from `render(controller(...))`, but from the configuration of SonataPageBundle.

Comment: I do not really remember all process of setuping project, but that was just couple of questions about hostname, site domain, my email etc, nothing special. Currently I see two records in page__site mysql table, related to this settings, and they all looks fine. I am just starting hate this system... it so frustrated, every day developing in it is like a challenge.

Comment: @Unstaged Could you post the contents of the table anyways?

Comment: `INSERT INTO `page__site` (`id`, `enabled`, `name`, `relative_path`, `host`, `enabled_from`, `enabled_to`, `is_default`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `locale`, `title`, `meta_keywords`, `meta_description`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'myproject.local', '/', 'myproject.local', '2014-11-19 18:35:30', '2024-11-19 18:35:30', 1, '2014-11-19 18:35:30', '2014-11-19 18:35:30', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);`

Comment: @Unstaged Does `myproject.local` match `mydomain.local` in your scenario? Or are you replacing values?

Comment: I am just replacing it, for avoid future "google searches", because actually it contains real company name.. but be sure, I've checked it, and hostname setuped correctly, Thanks for you help, but I think I need to solve it by myself with some alcohol and deep debuging process in symfony sources :) I was just hoping that someone here already faced with same issue..